# How can I simulate OpenFile in FFmpeg?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, buffer, hook

Most gif capture software capture screen and then save them one by one single frame picture file on disk,then read them into memory and combine them to gif,makes the whole procdure very slowly.

I got a idea to capture screen with DirectX(so we could also capture directx window faster since it direct operate the screen d3d device)API to got the bitmap，then save them to memory(such as buffer),then passing the memory location to ffmpeg to produce a video so we don't need disk storge as a middle buffer so it could be ten more faster since the disk is now most slowly part on pc now.

the directx capture screen part is already.But I found that ffmpeg using OpenFile to read the picture file,so here may we can simulate the OpenFile?
If answer is yes,how could we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a named pipe and use that as a source.

An example:
`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec ravideo -s $width$x$height$ -r $framerate -pix_fmt $pixelFormat$ -i "\\.\pipe\$pipeName$" Output.gif`

You have to fix the format of the frames you are going to feed FFmpeg, hence the `-s` and the `-pix_fmt` parameters.